# Why does `$(item).width()` return `0` even though elements exist?

Tags: jquery

With this code, I am trying to center an item depending width:

```
var name_ = 'Random name';
$('.arrow .text').text(name_);              
$('.arrow .text').css({'marginLeft':'-'+$('.arrow .text').width()/2+'px'});
console.log($('.arrow .text').length +' '+ $('.arrow .text').width() );
```

HTML

```
<div style="float:left;">
        <div class="map">
            <div class="arrow">
                <img src="http://www.discoverdartmouth.com/images/map.point.png" />
                <div class="text"></div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.freepik.es/foto-gratis/mapa-del-mundo_17-903095345.jpg" id="img1" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span class="spain mPointer">Spain</span> <span class="australia mPointer">Australia</span>
        </div>                      
    </div>
```

The line setting margin is not working and the console log is outputting `"1 0"`, so the item exists but has no width.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML. This sounds like something that should be achieved using HTML/CSS and not JS/jQuery.

Comment: Don't use jQuery to center HTML elements. That is what CSS is for.

Comment: margin: 0 auto;
to center it just using css, but not jquery

Comment: Edited: the problem is that .arrow is absolute positioned, and .text can have variable width. So i need to position the text acording the image, so i do think i need javascript here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; empty elements can have `0` width.

Elements that aren't in the DOM tree will also have `0` width.

Comment: but this item is not empty and it is in the DOM tree... so why width is returning 0 ??